# iPhone screen sleep - built in proximity sensor

Tags: iphone, ios, sleep, proximitysensor

Bon jour

is it possible to implement the following:

a. user places the iphone screen side down.
b. the screen sleeps (black) 
c. the app reamins in foreground with full functionality

I believe other apps might achieve this with the proximity sensor?

Will this drain the battery significantly?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].proximityMonitoringEnabled = YES;
BOOL shouldDimScreen = [UIDevice currentDevice].proximityState;

if (shouldDimScreen) {
    // do whatever you want
} else {
    // light the screen back up
}
```

You can use `NSNotificationCenter` to register for the `UIDeviceProximityStateDidChangeNotification` if you'd like to know every time the status changes.

But, iOS will automatically turn off the screen for you if the user doesn't touch it for a while.  So as long as you don't [turn off the idle timer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW63) your battery life will be fine, and you might not need to implement this.